# Machine Sounds in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I want add machine sounds to my router table simulator program. The idea is to hear the stepper motors accelerate and decelerate with a change in pitch synced with my graphics. Same with the spindle motor, it has a pitch change as its rpm goes up and down. I thought of either adding real recorded motor sounds and modifying the pitch at run time or create synthetic sounds simulating the motors. Can anyone suggest the easiest way to achieve this? I have hardly any experience in sound programming besides the most basic stuff. I am programming in C# in Visual Studio.net

Answer (score 1):

check these links out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavplayfx.aspx
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators

These should give an idea for the options (playing pre-recorded audio with some effects versus generating the sound synthetically) you mentioned, either way...